# Execution time of a Neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I created this simple example of Neo4j graph:

```
CREATE (n1:A), (n2:B), (n2:C), (n4:D)
Added 4 labels, created 4 nodes

MATCH(a:A), (b:B), (c:C), (d:D)
CREATE (d)<-[r3:r3]-(a)-[r1:r1]->(b)-[r2:r2]->(c)
```

Now I made this query on this graph:

```
MATCH (c:C)<-[r3]-(b:B)<-[r2]-(a:A)-[r1]->(d:D)
RETURN c,d
```

I did the query 13 times and I get different time of execution:

```
 1. 72 ms
 2. 68 ms
 3. 81 ms
 4. 25 ms
 5. 44 ms
 6. 22 ms
 7. 24 ms
 8. 53 ms
 9. 45 ms 
10. 67 ms
11. 86 ms
12. 83 ms
13. 90 ms
```

I'm searching for an inefficient query in Neo4j and I know that Neo4j queries lose their efficient when the oriented graph grows up in deep.
I don't understand why the fourth, the sixth and the seventh time the execution time is about 25 ms.
Finally, the execution time is reliable? Are queries like this a bit inefficient?

Comment: Your queries are global graph queries across the whole graph, try to use PROFILE in front of your query to see how much data they touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using a neo4j server. The timing differences you see are very minor and to be expected whenever making requests to any server.

Comment: Yes they include for instance roundtrip latency. Neo4j-Shell gives you better timings.